# datatable column header alignment issue

Tags: datatable, header, alignment

The issue is with chrome and IE. 
If we add scrolling option while making datatable the table header not aligned with the table. otherwise it is fine.

```
"scrollY" : 200, "scrollCollapse" : true, "sScrollX" : "100px",
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi we can solve the issue by adding our own custom scrolling facility.

- steps:)

  1. remove the scroll options while making datatable.
  2. wrap the table with div:
     `$('#'+tableId).wrap("<div class='scrolledTable'></div>");`
  3. give css property for scrolledTable class.

  .scrolledTable{ overflow-y: auto; clear:both; }

  1. Finish.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks so much.

Comment: tried many ways to fix it - this is the solution! thanks

Answer (score 7):

This may help,

```
$(".dataTables_scrollHeadInner").css({"width":"100%"});
$(".table ").css({"width":"100%"});
```

I placed it in my drawCallback function, and that worked for me(you can add it to yourstyle.css)

Answer (score 0):

If the table's html is created programmatically, I needed  a delay between creating the html and creating the table itself. It's possible that the delay needs changing for different browsers.

```
$(tableID + 'Table').html('<table class="display" id="' + tableID.substring(1) + '"></table>');
this.show = function (onclick) {
    // onclick is the function (if any) to be run when a row is clicked
    var defs = this.tableDefs;
    // workaround delay to allow column headers to be resized. Needs a delay after being created, before being shown
    setTimeout(function () {
        table = $(tableID).DataTable(defs);
        $(tableID + ' tbody tr').on('click', function () {
            var nTds = $('td', this);
            onclick(nTds);
        });
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write,

```
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").width($(".dataTables_scrollHead").width());
```

also write `"scrollX": true`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('#DataTableID').DataTable({
  //"scrollX": true,            
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
    $("#DataTableID").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simple and working fine solution you can use it

If we are using datatable scroll,Dom itself create two times table and thead but in scroll body thead height is 0 set by library.

Please remove all external padding whatever added by you it will work fine

**Remove Padding whatever added by other CSS, keep only datable library padding**